# python3: can't open file [Errno 2] No such file or directory on nodejs python spawn

Tags: python, node.js

In my application i am spawning python processes from nodejs

While performing a load test of about 15, i encountered this error.

There are several functions from nodejs which are calling this process

i am using centos8 and python 3.6.x

this is my dir structure

`/path/to/my/app/src/dboperations/db/<all the python files here>`

here is the full error

```
/usr/bin/python3: can't open file '/path/to/my/app/src/dboperations/db/myPyFile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

here is my code

```
const python = spawn(process.env.pythonPath, [__dirname+'/db/' + pyFile, JSON.stringify(recievedData)]);   //pyfile is the name of the file

python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {

                    dataToSend = dataToSend + data.toString();

                });

                python.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
                        dataToSend = dataToSend + data;

                });
                python.on('close', (code) => {
                    if (code == 0) {
return dataToSend  //success
}else{
return dataToSend //error
}
});
```

on the output i got the error,

the file which was mentioned in the error is actually there in the directory and they ran successfully in the previous function calls

i have a doubt is using the `__dirname` is the problem?

I got another way to refering the path of the python file to spawn

```
const python = spawn(process.env.pythonPath, [process.cwd() +'/dboperations/db/'+ pyFile, JSON.stringify(recievedData)]);
```

can somebody help me in figuring this error out?

Comment: Check if the path is relative maybe. It could be that the file can be accessed in the other methods that you mention.

Comment: the path mentioned in the error is correct, and __dirname ins nodejs gives you the current dir absloute path right?

Comment: I'm not sure about the __dirname method, is it a built-in method of python or are you taking it from somewhere else?

Comment: its not in python, its from nodejs, i am calling(spawing the python process) from nodejs

Comment: Could you maybe add the python code that tries to access the file too?